# how to get ng-repeat checkbox values on submit function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which has 10 checkboxes. By default angular js triggers on individual checkbox. I want to grab all selected check box values on submit action only. Here is my code...

```
<form name="thisform" novalidate data-ng-submit="booking()">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="standard" flex="50">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="typeValues[item._id]" value="{{item._id}}"/>
            {{ item.Service_Categories}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

---

```
$scope.check= function() { 
    //console.log("a");
    $http.get('XYZ.com').success(function(data, status,response) { 
    $scope.items=data;
});

$scope.booking=function(){
    $scope.typeValues = [];
    console.log($scope.typeValues);
}
```

I am getting empty array.

Can somebody tell how to grab all selected checkbox values only on submit event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.SELECTED"  ng-true-value="Y" ng-false-value="N"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check(items)"/>

$scope.check= function(data) { 
    var arr = [];
    for(var i in data){
       if(data[i].SELECTED=='Y'){
           arr.push(data[i].id);
       }
    }
    console.log(arr);
    // Do more stuffs here
}
```

Comment: actually im new to angularjs .i am getting error like this Error: [ngModel:constexpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ngModel/constexpr?p0=ngTrueValue&p1=Y
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:6:417

Comment: script>
  angular.module('info', [])
    .controller('FormController', ['$scope','$http','$window','$location', function($scope,$http,$window,$location,$stateProvider) 
 {
 $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.items = [{id:1},{id:2}];
    $scope.check= function(data) { 
    var arr = [];
    for(var i in data){
       if(data[i].SELECTED=='Y'){
           arr.push(data[i].id);
       }
    }
    console.log(arr);
    $scope.selected = arr;
    // Do more stuffs here
    }
   
    }]);my controller i am getting same error ngModel:constexpr

Comment: Try Using ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'" in html

Comment: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.SELECTED"  ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/>{{item}}
it's working for me thanks

Comment: how can i pass data to mongodb like this  ['Wash', 'Tyres', 'Spares', 'Accessories'];

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest reading the answer I posted yesterday to a similar StackOverflow question..

[AngularJS with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976425/how-to-filter-through-a-table-using-ng-repeat-checkboxes-with-angularjs/30977408#30977408)

This displayed a few checkboxes, then bound them to an array, so we would always know which of the boxes were currently checked.

[image]

And yes, you could ignore the contents of this bound variable until the submit button was pressed, if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code all the checkboxes values will be available in the typeValues array. You can use something like this in your submit function:

```
$scope.typeValues
```

If you want to access the value of 3rd checkbox then you need to do this:

```
var third = $scope.typeValues[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `ng-model` as array in controller, like

```
$scope.typeValues = [];
```

And in your template, please use

```
ng-model="typeValues[item._id]"
```

And in your controller, you will get this `model array values` in terms of `0` and `1`. You can iterate over there.

Comment: i am getting empty array

Comment: Are you getting an array with total items, which you had in `items` object ?

Comment: i am getting total length